# Cannot mention user via Teams bot using BotFramework API

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have fully configured and working Teams bot. It's able to start conversations with users and reply to their input. Now I want to **mention user** via my Teams bot in a **group chat** where that user is present.

I found docs describing how to achieve this:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-format?tabs=adaptive-md%2Cdesktop%2Cconnector-html#mention-support-within-adaptive-cards
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/channel-and-group-conversations?tabs=json#user-mention

I send the same payload as described in docs, but the content appearing in Teams has no mention or highlighting of the user, **just regular text**.

*I test this on Web version of Teams and also on iOS.*

So I tried this request:

```
POST https://smba.trafficmanager.net/apis/v3/conversations/{groupChatId}/activities

{
    "type": "message",
    "text": "Hey <at>Oleh</at>, check out this message!",
    "from": {
        "id": "{botId}",
        "name": "TestBot"
    },
    "conversation": {
        "id": "{groupChatId}"
    },
    "entities": [
        {
            "type":"mention",
            "mentioned":{
                "id":"{userId}",
                "name":"Oleh"
            },
            "text": "<at>@Oleh</at>"
        }
    ]
}
```

And text appears in Teams without user mentioning.

Also tried with Adaptive Cards - copied sample from [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-format?tabs=adaptive-md%2Cdesktop%2Cconnector-html#sample-adaptive-card-with-a-mention) - behaviour is the same. Adaptive card is rendered correctly, but with no user mention.

I tried to put different user ID into "entities[0].mentioned.id" field:

- user Teams ID (in the format "29:...")
- user AAD Object ID
- user email

And still no luck.

Am I passing something wrong, or it's an issue on the Teams side?

---

**UPD Resolved!**

After some digging I found that my raw request did not work as expected because I used different API url.

> [https://smba.trafficmanager.net/apis/v3/conversations/{converrsationId}/activities](https://smba.trafficmanager.net/apis/v3/conversations/%7BconverrsationId%7D/activities)

sends message, but with broken mentions.
Instead, this one:

> [https://smba.trafficmanager.net/emea/v3/conversations/{converrsationId}/activities](https://smba.trafficmanager.net/emea/v3/conversations/%7BconverrsationId%7D/activities)

works as expected.

Comment: I noticed in this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/channel-and-group-conversations?tabs=json#user-mention) that the JSON activity example includes the "@" symbol in the entities text field but is not included in the activity text field. Doc says the entities text field should match some portion of the activities text field. It may be a typo in their doc. The TypeScript and Python examples don't appear to include the "@" symbol. Maybe try removing it from both fields or adding it into both and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! But it didn't help. I just tried to send entities[0].text without "@" symbol - no luck. Also tried some combinations of including/excluding "@" from two <at> tag occurrences - all the same. Tested in both Classic Teams and New Teams.

Comment: @Oleg Could you please refer this sample-https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/0309a30b2a4bf9930fbbc30d610b7627d1821dc0/samples/bot-formatting-cards/csharp

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the suggestion! This one works, added resolved info to the description.